# Docpad Server Side Scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, docpad

I am new to docpad, and so far it is a pretty nice way to get a bunch of docs served up.  I am wondering where to put server side scripts?  I tried just wrapping what I want done server side in eco tags and I get the warning that

```
Rendering the extension "eco" to "html" on "search.html.eco" didn't do anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an indication that you have no eco code inside the file, although your post suggests that you had put code in the doc. It doesn't do any harm, except wasting the computer's time! ;-)

It will go away as soon as a `<% .... %>` is found in the doc